# Weak control of FWER

Tags: reference-request, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have $p$ null hypotheses $H_1,\ldots,H_p$ and the global hypothesis:
$$
H_0:H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \cdots \cap H_p.
$$
I'm interested in level controlling when testing for $H_0$ (using multiple testing): bounding
$$
\Pr(\text{reject }H_0|H_0\text{ is true})
$$
regardless of the underlying dependence of the individual tests used to test $H_1,\ldots,H_p$. As this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures) explains, I am in fact interested in controlling the family-wise error rate (FWER) in the **weak** sense.

The same article lists 2 methods of FWER level control (Bonferroni and Holm) that are robust to dependence of the individual tests. But these control FWER in the **strong** sense (defined in the article). So they work for my purpose but I'm afraid they are "overcompensating." What are some (modern) references for FWER level control in the **weak** sense?

Comment: How is defined as weak and strong?

Comment: Weak = level control for the probability of rejecting a true null when all the nulls are true; strong = level control for the probability of rejecting a true null.

Comment: @V.Vancak No. You should read the linked Wiki article and its subsidiary links. (This may save you time: in Wiki's notation, FWER deals with V whereas FDR deals with V/R.)

Comment: The only modern approach that I aware of is variations of FDR. It does not fit to your task?

Comment: @V.Vancak I don't think so, not for this specific task anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to **Remark 3.2** from [1], FDR coincides with weak FWER:

Given that all null hypotheses are null, any discovery is a false discovery, and therefore, $$FDP = V/R = 1.$$ ($V$ = # of false discoveries, $R$ = # of discoveries)

As you can see, under the condition that all nulls are true, the definitions of Type I error of a multiple test and FDP already coincide.

Since $FDR = E(FDP)$, when FDR is controlled at level $\alpha$, the Type I error given all nulls are true is controlled at level $\alpha$ as well.

Thus, FDR is a good choice for your problem.

[1] Rosenblatt, Jonathan: A Practitioner's Guide to Multiple Testing Error Rates. Available online at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.4920v3